# Checkboxes not checking after adding disabled attribute

Tags: angular

I have a list of items with checkboxes, and I would like to disable the ability to check off those boxes after a user has checked off 10 items from the list.

I am new to the world of Angular, so I am not clear why my use of `[disabled]` is not working:

```
<mat-selection-list appScrollable #filteredItemsSelectionList class="filtered-countries-list shaded>
  <mat-list-option appOffsetTop *ngFor="let item of filteredItems" [value]="item.name" checkboxPosition="before" [disabled]="filteredItems.length > 10">
     {{item.name}} {{item.address}} <span>{{item.phone}}</span>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

I attempted something like this in the past:

```
<mat-selection-list appScrollable #filteredItemsSelectionList shaded" [disabled]="filteredCountries.length >= 10">
  <mat-list-option (selectedChange)="onChange($event, item)" appOffsetTop *ngFor="let item of filteredItems" [value]="item.name" checkboxPosition="before" [disabled]="filteredItems.length > 10">
     {{item.name}} {{item.address}} <span>{{item.phone}}</span>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

And then in my component class file:

```
filteredItems = [];

onChange(selected: boolean, items: string) {
  this.filteredItems.push(item);
}
```

Since the work I have done above only served to completely disable the ability to click on checkboxes, I decided to console log `event` and `selectedOptions` to get the appropriate type and was able to get it at least for one of the parameters.

So instead what I landed on that is getting closer is removing `[disabled]` entirely I believe and doing it like so:

```
<mat-selection-list (selectionChange)="disableMaxSelection($event, filteredItemsSelectionList.selectedOptions)" appScrollable #filteredItemsSelectionList shaded" [disabled]="filteredItems.length >= 10">
  <mat-list-option (selectedChange)="onChange($event, item)" appOffsetTop *ngFor="let item of filteredItems" [value]="item.name" checkboxPosition="before" [disabled]="filteredItems.length > 10">
     {{item.name}} {{item.address}} <span>{{item.phone}}</span>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

So now I am depending on a `selectionChange` called `disableMaxSelection()` like so:

```
disableMaxSelection(event: MatSelectionListChange, selectedOptions) {}
```

And now I think I got it, but I might need some help with the logic here, something like comparing with current selected filter and if item is not in filter, don't disable? Not sure.

I have tried repeatedly to implement the use of `[disabled]=""` but it disables my checkboxes every single time. And my data is not an array of strings, it's an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any event specified in your element, try adding `selectedChange` onto your `mat-list-option`, also, you should add the `disabled` in the element container rather than the option.

I have taken an example from the offical [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api):

**Template HTML**

```html
<mat-selection-list [disabled]="shoesSelected.length > 3"> <!--disable goes here-->
  <mat-list-option 
   (selectedChange)="onChange($event, shoe)" <!-- listen to this event -->
   *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
    {{ shoe }}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**Component**

```js
...
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  typesOfShoes: string[] = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins',  'Sneakers'];
  shoesSelected: string[] = [];

  onChange(selected: boolean, shoe: string) {
    // ... do something with selected
    this.shoesSelected.push(shoe);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check if the length>10 and is not selected.

You can play with two properties:

1. options: a QueryList
2. selectedOptions.selected.length: how many items are you selected

So, if you write some like

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes;let i=index"
     [disabled]="shoes.selectedOptions.selected.length>2 &&
                 !isSelected(i,shoes.options)
                  ">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Your function isSelected like

```
  isSelected(index:number,options:QueryList<MatListOption>)
  {
    if (!options)
      return;
    const option= options.find((x,i)=>i==index)
    return option && option.selected
  }
```

See how you can find the option of a QueryList by index using the "second argument of find"

And you get it

NOTE: You can use some like

```
  getValue(options:QueryList<MatListOption>)
  {
    if (!options)
      return null;
    return this.typesOfShoes.filter((x,index)=>this.isSelected(index,options));
  }
```

To get the values selected

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grv1wq?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.ts)

**Personal Opinion** To control a series of check-boxes I feel is easer  use a FormArray of FormControls or a simple [(ngModel)] using an array than fight with QueryLists

**Update** another way to control

e.g. Imagine we has a variable

```
selected:string[]=[]
```

And some like

```
<div *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes;let i=index">
  <mat-checkbox
    [checked]="selected.indexOf(shoe)!=-1"
    (change)="change(shoe,$event.checked)"
    [disabled]="selected.length>2 && selected.indexOf(shoe)==-1"
    >{{shoe}}</mat-checkbox
  >
</div>
```

The function change

```
  change(value:string,checked:boolean)
  {
    const oldValue=this.selected || []
    if (!checked)
      this.selected=this.typesOfShoes.filter(
                x=>oldValue.indexOf(x)!=-1 && x!=value)
    else
      this.selected=this.typesOfShoes.filter(
                x=>oldValue.indexOf(x)!=-1 || x==value)
  }
```

You get it again

Comment: It's a bit complex. The property seletedOptions is of type [SelectionModel<MatListOption>](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/collections/selection-model.ts). SelectionModel is a class that has differents methods and properties. One property (you can see as "getter" is `selected` (that return an array of MatListOption) with the option selected. You can try use `shoes.selectedOptions && shoes.selectedOptions.selected.length>2 && !isSelected(i,shoes.options)`. When we has a serie of conditions concatenate by && if one is false don't execute the rest of conditions.

Comment: @Daniel, I update the answer to give another approach using simple checkbox